# Not able to fetch UIButton through its tag

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, uidatepicker

I have 4 `UIButton`s named morningbutton, afternoonbutton, eveningbutton, and nightbutton where it has tag number 1, 2, 3, 4 ..and it is allocated in `viewDidLoad`. I am calling userTimepickerValuechanged method in `viewDidLoad` and it is being called for datepicker and notificationbuttonchanged method is called by `UIButton`s.

> UPDATE 
>    - selectedButton is an NSInteger

User taps 1 of 4 tagged buttons
(notificationButtonChanged gets called)

User changes value of date picker
(userTimePickerValueChanged gets called)

When I tap a button based on tag notificationButtonChanged gets called and datepicker with custom time display when I select a time in datepicker that time should get stored in usertimepickerchanged method ..but selectedButton is returning 0.

If I put selectedButton = afternoonButton.tag ..then 2nd case gets executed how should do that all the 4 cases.

Where am I going wrong?

```
    -(IBAction)notificationButtonChanged:(UIButton *)control
    {
    if (control.tag == 1)
    {
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];

        [components setHour:6];;
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:10];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:date2];

    }

    if (control.tag == 2)
    {
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];


        [components setHour:12];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:14];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:date2];

    }

    if (control.tag == 3)
    {
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];


        [components setHour:15];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:18];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:date2];


    }

    if (control.tag == 4)
    {
        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];


        [components setHour:19];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date1 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:22];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:date1];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:date2];

    }
}

-(void) userTimePickerValueChanged:(UIButton *)sender
{
    selectedButton = [sender tag];

       switch (selectedButton)
    {
case 1:
    {
        NSUserDefaults *userSelectedMorningTime = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSDate *selectedMorningTime = [userTimePicker date];

        NSLog (@"SETTING: morningTimeKey");

        [userSelectedMorningTime setObject:selectedMorningTime forKey:@"morningTimeKey"];
        [userSelectedMorningTime synchronize];
    }
    break;
    case 2:
        {

            NSUserDefaults *userSelectedAfternoonTime = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            NSDate *selectedAfternoonTime = [userTimePicker date];

            NSLog (@"SETTING: afternoonTimeKey");

            [userSelectedAfternoonTime setObject:selectedAfternoonTime forKey:@"afternoonTimeKey"];
            [userSelectedAfternoonTime synchronize];


        }break;
        case 3:
        {


            NSUserDefaults *userSelectedEveningTime = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            NSDate *selectedEveningTime =[userTimePicker date];

            NSLog (@"SETTING: eveningTimeKey");

            [userSelectedEveningTime setObject:selectedEveningTime forKey:@"eveningTimeKey"];
            [userSelectedEveningTime synchronize];


        }break;
        case 4:
        {

            NSUserDefaults *userSelectedNightTime = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            NSDate *selectedNightTime =[userTimePicker date];

            NSLog (@"SETTING: nightTimeKey");

            [userSelectedNightTime setObject:selectedNightTime forKey:@"nightTimeKey"];
            [userSelectedNightTime synchronize];

        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    userTimePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [userTimePicker addTarget: self
                   action: @selector(userTimePickerValueChanged:)forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];


    morningButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    morningButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    afternoonButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    afternoonButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    eveningButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    eveningButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    nightButton =[[UIButton alloc]init];
    nightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];


 }



    -(IBAction)settingsButtonChanged:(UIButton *)sender
{

    settingsView.frame = CGRectMake(25.0, 60.0, 280.0, 400.0);

    morningButton.tag = 1;
    morningButton.frame = CGRectMake(25.0, 20.0, 80.0, 40.0);
    morningButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [morningButton setTitle:@"Morning" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    afternoonButton.tag =2;
    afternoonButton.frame = CGRectMake(185.0, 20.0, 80.0, 40.0);
    afternoonButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [afternoonButton setTitle:@"Afternoon" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    eveningButton.tag = 3;
    eveningButton.frame = CGRectMake(25.0, 70.0, 80.0, 40.0);
    eveningButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [eveningButton setTitle:@"Evening" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    nightButton.tag = 4;
    nightButton.frame = CGRectMake(185.0, 70.0, 80.0, 40.0);
    nightButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [nightButton setTitle:@"Night" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    userTimePicker.frame = CGRectMake(60.0, 194.0, 150.0, 180.0);
    userTimePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;

    [morningButton addTarget:self action:@selector(notificationButtonChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [afternoonButton addTarget:self action:@selector(notificationButtonChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [eveningButton addTarget:self action:@selector(notificationButtonChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [nightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(notificationButtonChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [self.view addSubview:remedyViewBackButton];
    [settingsView addSubview:morningButton];
    [settingsView addSubview:afternoonButton];
    [settingsView addSubview:eveningButton];
    [settingsView addSubview:nightButton];


    [settingsView addSubview:userTimePicker];
    [remedyView addSubview:remedyViewBackButton];
    [remedyView addSubview:settingsView];
}
```

Comment: added viewdidload code

Comment: Where are you setting the tags? Also, as other have said below, you're calling the userTimePickerValueChanged from the picker, not buttons.

Comment: where you have assigned tag to buttons

Comment: i have assigned tags in settingsbuttonchanged method

Comment: set tags here in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are not set tag for this, it is by default assigned as 0. if you have assigned tag to it, then somewhere in code you are reassigning tag 0 to it, check where it is reassigning.
assign tag more than 1000 & then try. means assign them 1000,1001,1002,1003 just for checking.

change your code to this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    userTimePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [userTimePicker addTarget: self
                   action: @selector(userTimePickerValueChanged:)forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];


    morningButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    morningButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

morningButton.tag=1;
    afternoonButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    afternoonButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
afternoonButton.tag=2;

    eveningButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    eveningButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

 eveningButton.tag=3;

    nightButton =[[UIButton alloc]init];
    nightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
nightButton.tag=4;


 }
```

also init all buttonss with `initWithFrame`

Answer (score 2):

When `-(void)userTimePickerValueChanged:(UIButton *)sender` gets invoked, the sender is the date picker, and you are incorrectly casting it to a UIButton*.  That tag will be the same value each time, the tag of the date picker itself, which is probably 0.

Not sure what function you're going for in that method, but the switch probably based on the *value* of the date picker, that is, the date picked.

Comment: then how do i fetch the date picked by datepicker when the button is pressed and pass it to userTimePickerValueChanged method

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you are doing, `userTimePickerValueChanged` is called by the time picker, so in

```
-(void) userTimePickerValueChanged:(UIButton *)sender
```

the sender will be the time picker, not any of your buttons. That explains why it does not work.

To work around this, you need to define a property in your class where you store the button which actually triggered the date picker to be displayed. Then you would do:

```
-(IBAction)notificationButtonChanged:(UIButton *)control
{
if (control.tag == 1)
{
   self.pressedButtonTag = control.tag;
   ...
```

and:

```
-(void) userTimePickerValueChanged:(UIButton *)sender
{
   switch (self.pressedButtonTag)
  {
```

If you feel like "lazy" and you do not want to create a specific property to keep track of the pressed button, you could dynamically re-assign the `datePicker.tag`:

```
-(IBAction)notificationButtonChanged:(UIButton *)control {
  if (control.tag == 1) {
    userTimePicker.tag = control.tag;
    ...
```

and:

```
-(void) userTimePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
   switch (sender.tag)
  {
```

Keep in mind that the second option is more of a hack, so I leave up to you deciding what you prefer doing, but in the second case add comments to explain how the thing works.

Comment: thanks i will look into .. if u want i can send u my .m file if it helps u

Comment: i should put userTimePicker.tag = control.tag; in rest of the if statement if i am correct ...like when control.tag == 2 , 3 ,4

Comment: btw of what type is pressedButtonTag and pressedButton in ur first option ... In userTimePickerValue method i'll have to create UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton*) sender and use pressedButton?

Comment: according to ur 2nd option ..when i choose sender.tag which is of uidatepicker. . based on which button i have chosen in notificationButtonChanged ..that case will get executed right .. like if i choose afternoonButton ..then 2nd case in userTimepickervalue changed method will get execute... if i choose eveningButton .then 3rd case

Comment: you are right about your first question; as to the second, that was a typo: I only though of using pressedButtonTag. will edit...

Comment: i can use pressedButtonTag as NSInteger ..can u explain me about my 2nd option query .Thanks

Comment: well, in that case, it is just the same logics. the only thing is that you "hijack" datepicker.tag to store the tag of the button which was pressed: when you handle the action for the button, you set the datepicker.tag, so that when you later handle the action for the date picker, you know which button was originally pressed because its tag is store in datepicker.tag. does this help?

Comment: Thanks Sergio I'll let u know about the result .Since I don't have Mac right now I am unable to test it...but I think the code which u have mentioned should work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24315/discussion-between-rock-rocky-and-sergio)

Comment: ..can u help me with this question .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811360/how-to-add-uiimage-to-tableviewcell#comment20746132_14811360